# Fetch database information in Json format data using php in Android

Tags: php, android, json, listview

I am getting the json data while running the php file but I failed to get it on the android page. I checked the connection also using

```
 //checking the connection with server-.php file
                    int i =response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

                    System.out.println(i); // Checking the connection,If connected i=200
```

And the connection is correct. The value of i=200.

There are no errors shown but still I am not able to get the data on android.

Php file:- SampleConLogin1.php

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","amodbina0106","Amodbina200","kezin_king");
if ($con->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
?>

<?php
$sql=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `Test` WHERE 1");
$result=array();
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
$vendorid=$row['Vendor_ID'];
$username=$row['username'];
$password=$row['password'];
?>

 <?php 
$a = array($vendorid,$username,$password);
array_push($result,$a);



}
echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));
?>
```

Output of .php file:-
The output generated after running the .php file

```
Connected successfully {"result":[["1","nupur","nupur"],["4","",""],["3","nupur","1234"],["5","RAJ","RAJ"],["6","RAJ","RAJ"],["7","",""],["8","",""],["9","",""],["10","",""],["11","",""],["12","RAM","RAM"],["13","RAM","RAM"],["14","RAM","RAM"],["15","RAM","RAM"],["16","Nupur","Nupur"],["17","Nupur","Nupur"],["18","Nupur","Nupur"],["19","Nupur","Nupur"],["20","Rohit","Rohit"],["21","RAM","RAM"],["22","",""],["23","",""],["24","RAM","RAM"],["35","SAGAR","SAGAR"],["34","SAGAR","SAGAR"],["33","SAGAR","SAGAR"],["32","RAM","RAM"],["31","",""],["36","SAGAR","SAGAR"],["37","SAGAR","SAGAR"],["38","SAGAR","SAGAR"],["39","SAGAR","SAGAR"],["40","SAGAR","SAGAR"],["41","SAGAR","SAGAR"],["73","",""],["43","SAGAR","SAGAR"],["44","SAGAR","SAGAR"],["45","SAGAR","SAGAR"],["46","SAGAR","SAGAR"],["47","username","password"],["74","SAGAR","SAGAR"],["75","SAGAR","SAGAR"],["72","Krishna","Krishna"],["68","Honey","Honey"],["69","Ram","Ram"],["70","Ram","Ram"],["71","Ram","Ram"]]}
```

Json data:- 
After using json editor I got this result in json format.As I am getting the json data from php file

```
-object     {1}

  -result       [47]

       -0       [3]

            0   :   1

            1   :   nupur

            2   :   nupur

      -1        [3]

           0    :   4

           1    :   

           2    :   

     -2       [3]

           0    :   3

           1    :   nupur

           2    :   1234

     -3       [3]

           0    :   5

           1    :   RAJ

           2    :   RAJ

    -4       [3]

         0  :   6

        1   :   RAJ

        2   :   RAJ

5       [3]

  ............................
```

**Android -MainActivity.Java**

```
package com.example.nupur.fetchjson;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
String myJson;
    private static final String TAG_RESULTS="result";
    private static final String TAG_VENDOR_ID="id";
    private static final String TAG_USERNAME="username";
    private static final String TAG_PASSWORD="password";
    JSONArray peoples =null;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> personList;
    ListView list;
   // TextView check;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        list=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        //check=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.check);
        personList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
        getData();
    }
    protected void showList(){
        try{
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJson);
            peoples = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);
          //  check.setText(myJson);

            for(int i=0;i<peoples.length();i++){
                JSONObject c = peoples.getJSONObject(i);
                String VENDOR_ID = c.getString(TAG_VENDOR_ID);
                String username = c.getString(TAG_USERNAME);
                String password = c.getString(TAG_PASSWORD);

                HashMap<String,String> persons = new HashMap<String,String>();

                persons.put(TAG_VENDOR_ID,VENDOR_ID);
                persons.put(TAG_USERNAME,username);
                persons.put(TAG_PASSWORD,password);

                personList.add(persons);
            }

            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    MainActivity.this, personList, R.layout.list_view,
                    new String[]{TAG_VENDOR_ID,TAG_USERNAME,TAG_PASSWORD},
                    new int[]{R.id.Vendor_id, R.id.username, R.id.password}
            );

            list.setAdapter(adapter);

        }catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void getData(){
        class getDATAJSON extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://kezinking.com/SampleConLogin1");
                // Depends on your web service
                httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
                InputStream inputStream = null;
                String result = null;
                try{
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                    inputStream = entity.getContent();
                    // json is UTF-8 by default
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    result = sb.toString();
                    //checking the connection with server-.php file
                    int i =response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

                    System.out.println(i); // Checking the connection,If connected i=200

                }catch (Exception e) {
                    // Oops
                }finally {
                    try{if(inputStream != null)inputStream.close();}catch(Exception squish){}
                }
                return result;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                myJson=result;
                showList();
            }
        }
        getDATAJSON g = new getDATAJSON();
        g.execute();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Android- **activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/check"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Android- **list_view.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp" >


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Vendor_id"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="2dip"
            android:paddingTop="6dip"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="2dip"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

Android:- **AndroidManifest.xml**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.nupur.fetchjson">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: What do you have in your  result  variable of doInBackground() ?

Comment: Do you get any error ?

Comment: In my result.
when i did System.out.println(result); I get
{"result":[{"Vendor_ID":"1","username":"nupur","password":"nupur"},{"Vendor_ID":"4","username":"","password":""},{"Vendor_ID":"3","username":"nupur","password":"1234"},{"Vendor_ID":"5","username":"RAJ","password":"RAJ"},{"Vendor_ID":"6","username":"RAJ","password":"RAJ"},{"Vendor_ID":"7","username":"","password":""},{"Vendor_ID":"8","username":"","password":""},{"Vendor_ID":"9","username":" ......................................so on

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you are trying to get data based on key from json response that you get from your php script. Inside your show data function you write like this to parse data from result json Array.

```
 JSONObject c = peoples.getJSONObject(i);
            String VENDOR_ID = c.getString(TAG_VENDOR_ID);
            String username = c.getString(TAG_USERNAME);
            String password = c.getString(TAG_PASSWORD);
```

but the result you get from your php script not contacting array of object it contain array of arrays.
 So your php file should give json response like this.

```
{"result":[{"Vendor_ID":"1","username":"nupur","password":"nupur"},{"Vendor_ID":"2","username":"abc","password":"xyz"}]}
```

In order to generate above json response you need to change your php script like this.

```
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","amodbina0106","Amodbina200","kezin_king");
if ($con->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
?>

<?php
$sql=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `Test` WHERE 1");
$result=array();
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
    $result[]=$row;
}
echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));
?>
```

One more change in your MainActvity change this line

```
private static final String TAG_VENDOR_ID="id";
```

to this

```
private static final String TAG_VENDOR_ID="Vendor_ID";
```

because you will get Vendor_ID in json response not id.

I hope this will help you.
If you found any problem feel free to ask.

Comment: Now my json data is coming in proper format. But still there is no result on Android.

Comment: echo "Connected successfully"; remove this line from your php code